# Using the tinker function in laravel

Tags: laravel, homestead, tinker

Im using the tinker function in laravel but when i type the following in:

```
>>>user App\PostController;
>>>PostController::get();
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/PostController' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: You can't just call a `controller` like that from `tinker`. What is it you're attempting to do?

Comment: Did you try `composer dump-autoload` to clear the cache?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
$controller = app()->make(App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);

app()->call([$controller, 'get']);
```

If you want to pass arguments to the method:

```
$controller = app()->make(App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class);

app()->call([$controller, 'get'], ['test' => 123]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Controllers are under App\Http\Controllers namespace
try `use App\Http\Controllers\PostController`

Comment: @GinoSesia did you double check class name in the file, it's namespace, etc? have you tried using the class and it's method in a test route and see if it will work? sometimes doing composer dump-autoload might help.try that and let me know if it helps